# Can entire emails be composed and sent with a PHP command?

Tags: php, email

I am following this guide:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

So by following this guide can I really send an email to myself (someemail@website.com) by opening this page I called "email.php" in Chrome or other internet browser?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Email Application </h1>

<?php
$to = "someemail@website.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "Some Guy";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried running email.php seen above locally but nothing happens. Do I need to put email.php on a server?

I'm currently working on a Contact Form and I want all the information entered in a contact form's fields to be sent to a specified email address. I'm doing this for a company's website.

Comment: PHP needs to be run through a web server; if you just open the file locally, it won't do anything.

Comment: @andrewsi that's right, plus the fact that you also need a `mail server` running alongside it.

Comment: A `web host` is your first step, then comes the cream & gravy. However, the code you posted, won't do a thing; well, sort of.

Comment: @reikyoushin You don't need a mail server.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ how so ? You need an SMTP for instance sendmail or similar available or a remote SMTP.

Comment: @Prix Socket connections to a mail server from PHP. Here's an example. Basically you're replicating what you can do with telnet via command line (you can send email from there too.) http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=557685

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ and how is that not a remote access like I have previously said ?

Comment: @Prix You're not using an SMTP server (or the php `mail()` function), you're connecting to the server where you're delivering the mail with a telnet-style socket connection.

Comment: You should put a real email address into the `From` field. And don't rely on w3schools.com, it's full of errors. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ you're still dependent on the mail server to delivery the message by remotely connecting to it indifferent to the way you do it.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Why did you change the email address? It's still in the message and, what's more important, it's in the history of this question.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel It's not relavent to the question or the answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address_harvesting

Comment: @Prix, by opening a socket connection you're not relying on another server to send your e-mail you're in effect creating your own SMTP server (in the eyes of the recipient's mail server).

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ you're still not removing the need of mail server and you said it yourself.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ : are you aware of any PHP project actually mimic'ing an SMTP server? So one can send emails with no smtp server at all ? If exists, I would like to know such a project

Comment: @nl-x I write them all the time. They allow me better logging than digging through `mail()` in some instances.

Comment: @nl-x If you only want to send mails to yourself, you can use a database to store messages in.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel No. I want a PHP script/library that actually open a socket to the receiving mail server op port 25, and send it an e-mail, without using  an SMTP (sending) server. And I would favor a more sophisticated open source project, as that would be better than what I can write by my self in a few days

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I already thought that, but the OP's mail address is still in this questions history. The OP should sent a mail to team@stackoverflow.com to ask the devs to remove old revisions. BTW, it's convention to use `something@example.com` as an example address; now the owners of website.com will be spammed.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel so make the edit. By removing it from the question here it's not visible on this page when someone crawls the site (so it's only in the history instead of in two locations).

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ ever shared one of your scripts to send mails without an SMTP server :) ?

Comment: @nl-x for money. Here's an open source library that builds on the `fsockopen()` function I was talking about. There's really no sense in not using a mail engine unless you're going to alter it in some crazy way. I use my proprietary code for pentesting SMTP, Mail Exchangers, and routers. https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ you still need a mail server, whether it is running on the same system as your web server or on other servers, in your case you are just using a mail server from 'another' system, but still you need a `mail server`

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ It still gets crawled, it's only one page further. And that's also why I asked Pankaj to make the change, to not make another revision (within 5 minutes there will be no new revision recorded).

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Argh, it's already implemented in PHPMailer? Sorry for asking then.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PHP can send e-mails. But you need to configure a mail (SMTP) server in php.ini.

If you have a mail server running locally, php.ini is set to use it by default. Don't forget to turn on the mail server and configure it to allow relaying of local mails.

I you have a remote mail server (you can even use [Google's SMTP server](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html)), set php.ini to use it.

You might want to change

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

into

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    echo "Mail Sent.";
else
    echo "Failed sending e-mail";
```

Comment: Indeed. Always check the result of the `mail` function to see if a mail got correctly sent.

Comment: Matt, does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This happened due to your smtp setup and not your code. You should verify that your smtp is properly set up.

Try using

```
echo ini_get("SMTP");
echo ini_get("smtp_port");
```

To get your SMTP details. Check your php.ini

It should be in this format

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25



     <?php
        $to = "something@email.com";
        $subject = "Test mail";
        $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: XYZ <xyz.com>\r\n";
        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        {
           echo "Mail Sent.";
        }
       else
        {
          echo "Mail Failed ";
         }        
?>
```